# Flutter dropdownbutton is not display current value selection

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, setstate, default-value, dropdownbutton

I have a menu where you filter geographical locations using two dropdown menus. Then the user proceeds to the main screen.

On the main screen, if the user wants to change the geographical location again, they can open up the filters again. I have a function on this screen to reselect their last search (so the two dropdowns and the list item). The previous screen passes details about the last search so I can reselect.

The problem is here, if I set the value of the DropdownButton, it just renders blank. Using debugging tools, it says the "value:" has been set to the correct value though, and if I press the dropdown, it's already scrolled to the position of that item on the drop down list.

Now I can just set the hinttext to give the illusion that it's selected, the problem is it needs to actually be set to the correct value as the user might just change one of the dropdowns. The dropdowns interact with each other in another function checking each others values, and if the values are not set, the user has to basically press the same selection again before it actually works (which is not desired obviously)

Can anyone help with what's wrong?

On main screen, the Dropdown is returned in a FutureBuilder after the connectionState is done

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: geoDataFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
            return const Center(child: CircularPorgressIndicator());
        }
        else {
            return MyCustomDropdown(
            hintText: geoDropDownHintText,
            dropDownList: listOfGeoTypes,
            dropDownValue: geoTypeValue,
            dropDownCallback: geoCallback,
            disableThisFilter: myCustomDropdownDisabled,
        )
```

On reselection function,

```
else if(widget.currentGeoFilters.geoType == "X"){
    setState(() {
        // Uncommenting the hint text assignment will still not let it display
        // geoDropDownHintText = widget.currentGeoFilters.geoType;
        geoTypeValue = widget.currentGeoFilters.geoType
        myCustomdropdownisabled = false;
    }
```

As you see I set things with variables

For my custom dropdown class, here is the functionality. Not shown is the class initialization with the required class variables, and other stuff like icons.

```
class _MyCustomDropdownstate extends State<MyCustomDropdown> {
    String selectedValue = "";
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: widget.disableThisFilter,
        child: DropdowButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
                value: widget.dropDownValue,
                hint: Text(widget.hintText, style: ... color: widget.disableThisFilter ?...),
                onChanged: (String? newValue){
                    widget.dropDownValue = newValue!;
                    selectedValue = widget.dropDownValue!;
                },
                selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return widget.dropDownList.map((String value) {
                        return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                            selectedValue, style: ...))
                    }).toList();
                },
         items: widget.dropDownList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: Text(value, style: ...)}).toList(),
```

So I'm not sure what's wrong, I imagine it's something regarding the UI refreshing and something with setState?

Comment: You should change widget.dropdownValue = newValue. Create a local variable and put it in the init state. You can then create a callback to notify the root widget.  Finally, change it to a dropdown instead of a local variable. 
If you call setstate twice in future builder, you might get a problem. Once again, create a local future value and set it on the widget. It just calls once.

Comment: @vb10 Sorry I'm not following. Create a local variable in my custom dropdown class? A callback, in the onChange method? But isn't onChanged only for when a user is selecting themselves? Could you make a code example? I'm not really following.